# Using Raspberry Pi3 as Lora gateway

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, spi, lora

I'm trying to use Pi3 as my LoRa gateway with sx1276 LoRa modules.

The module with sx1276 chip and single channel connect via SPI interface.

Test with Arduino are work great. Both send and receive are success.

But there's some problem when I was trying to connect Raspberry Pi3.

The source code [node-sx127x][1] is from Gitub, it is a install by npm and node.js.

So far seems good and the sender.js run great on my Pi3, the data will be received by Arduino code.

But the receive.js could not receive any data from any nodes!

The register process seems good, because the Pi will print "open success" after it catch the SPI and Lora module!

I've been tested the frequency and bandwith from sx127x.js, it is available when I change the value.

And both of sender.js and receive.js are using the default value from sx127x.js.
So I'm not sure what's the problem.

The modules I used are sx1276. I've tried two modules but the result are the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xYaq.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEi32.png)

Comment: RFM95 and SX1276 are different modules. Not sure that one driver will work for both. They also have different frequencies for the RF.

Comment: @Kevin Sorry for misunderstand. I'm using sx1276 with SPI interface modules as the pictures. And the code I use are from https://github.com/sandeepmistry/node-sx127x

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a second RaspberryPi to ensure your problem isn't in the Arduino. If the Pi-Pi connection works you have to look into the arduino script. Otherwise your pi is not working.

You could also try Arduino-Arduino connection.

could you post your Arduino send script

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Arduino to Arduino are work great. But Pi to Pi can't be received. I've been  tested with another Pi board and make sure that the Pi is ok.

Comment: You can try another script. I think this could work https://github.com/mayeranalytics/pySX127x

Comment: Thanks for sharing great code! I ran the test code and showed the hardware information with lora_util.py. But I can't find any example code to test the send and receive functions.